# Showing that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is a countable set.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working through Understanding Analysis by Abbott and was wondering about the correctness of my solution to a problem in section 1.4. Exercise 1.4.10 asks:

> Show that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is a countable set.

So my idea for a solution is to use induction. The base case is simple, with each element of $\mathbb{N}$ mapping to a singleton of itself. Clearly we have a bijection and thus all the subsets of size 1 are countable. From here we assume that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ of size $k-1$ is a countable set. Let $\{B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4, \dots \}$ be an enumeration of the subsets of size $k-1$ of $\mathbb{N}$. For a given $i \in \mathbb{N}$, the family $\{B_k \cup \{i\} : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is similarly countable. The family on subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ of size $k$ can then be written as the union

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty{\left\{B_k \cup \{i\} : k \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}.$$

This is a countable union of countable families of sets and is thus countable. So, the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ of size $k$ is countable and thus by induction this statement holds true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now let $A_i$ be the family of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ of size $i$. By above each of these families is countable. Thus

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty{A_i}$$

is the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and since it is a countable union of countable families of sets our result follows.

Is this a valid proof? The only thing I'm a little unsure of is writing the family of subsets of size $k$ as I do in that first union. Any other comments are welcome as well.

Comment: Okay, so thinking about it more the family of size subsets of size $k$ is actually a subset of that first union so it is still countable via induction, since it is a subset of a countable set. I think this should be completely correct then, no?

Comment: You will have a much easier time proving this by instead of breaking into cases based on the size of the subset to instead break into cases based on the largest appearing element in the subset.  The start of the list following this method is: $\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{3\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\},\{4\},\dots$ and each case has only finitely many subsets in it.

Comment: $$X\mapsto1+\sum_{x\in X}2^{x-1}$$

Comment: @jmoravitz That’s a great way of thinking about it and it works well, also it’s intuitive. Do you think my solution works given the correction I made in my comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the minor correction made in your comment (the family of $k$-subsets is *contained* in the union you wrote; it's not *equal* to that union, because the union contains some $(k-1)$-subsets as well), your proof is correct.  I would probably write it in a way that makes no use of enumerations of the countable sets involved... other answers show that there are very clean ways to prove the countability of $\cal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ specifically, so it's nice for you to have a slightly more abstract approach:

> Thm: If $X$ is a countable set, then so is ${\cal{P}}(X)$.

Proof (OP):

Let $A_k(X)$ be the set of $k$-subsets of $X$.   We will show that $A_k(X)$ is countable for each $k$, by induction.  Clearly $A_0(X)=\{\emptyset\}$ is countable.  For $k\ge 1$, assume $A_{k-1}(X)$ is countable.  We have
$$
A_{k}(X)=\bigcup_{x\in X}\bigcup_{Y\in A_{k-1}(X) : x\notin Y}\{Y\cup\{x\}\}.
$$
This is a countable union (since $X$ is countable) of countable unions (since $A_{k-1}(X)$ is countable by hypothesis) of finite sets; hence it is a countable union of countable sets; hence it is countable.  By induction, then, $A_k(X)$ is countable for all $k$.  We conclude that $${\cal{P}}(X)=\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}A_k(X)$$
is also a countable union of countable sets, and hence countable.
$\;\square$

Comment: That helped clear it up for me! The other methods where we find an explicit bijection are nice, but to me they don't really illustrate what is happening so much. Breaking the subsets into their respective sizes seemed like a natural first step so it was good to see it can be worked out that way.

Comment: if $X$ is the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, then $\mathbb{N} \in {\cal{P}}(X)   $.  But I am not sure that $\mathbb{N} \in \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}A_k(X)$ holds. Nevertheless, you have proved that the set of all finite subsets of $X$ countable
is a countable set.

Comment: @311411: You're right, my notation is poor... I'm using ${\cal P}(X)$ throughout to denote the set of *finite* subsets of $X$, not the usual power set.

Comment: oh ok, if that was your intended meaning, then it is alright.

Answer (score 1):

First order the prime numbers: let $p_1=2$ and let $p_n$ be the nth prime starting from 2. Now let $X \subset \Bbb N$ be finite. Assume that $X = \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ and $x_i < x_{i+1}$ for $1\leq i \leq n-1$. If $\mathfrak{P}(\Bbb N)$ denotes the collection of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$, then let $\psi:\mathfrak{P}(\Bbb N) \to \Bbb N$ be a function which is defined by

\begin{equation}
\psi(X) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{x_1}
\end{equation}

By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, $\psi$ is one-one. This shows that $\mathfrak{P}(\Bbb N)$ is countable.

Comment: $x_4$ should be $x_i$ ... nice proof

Answer (score -1):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b_m b_{m-1}\ldots b_2 b_1 b_0$ be its expansion in binary. There are technically an infinite number of $0$'s to the left of the expansion, so it makes sense to talk about bits $b_r$, for $r > m$.

The binary expansion of a number provides a natural way to talk about the subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Each bit is either $1$ or $0$, and each element of $\mathbb{N}$ is either *in* or *not in* a given subset.

For $n$ as described above with a binary expansion $b_m b_{m-1}\ldots b_2 b_1 b_0$, construct the subset of $\mathbb{N}$ specified by $\{a \in \mathbb{N} \vert b_{a-1} = 1\}$. This subset is finite since $n$ is finite, and therefore has a finite binary expansion. Moreover, since binary expansions are unique, no two natural numbers can specify the same subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ can be associated with a unique binary expansion (and consequently, a unique natural number), showing that this construction is bijective.

Since $\mathbb{N}$ is countable and the set of finite subsets is bijective to $\mathbb{N}$, this set is also countable.